# Angular-ui router loading jade template

Tags: angularjs, express, pug, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to combine Express with Angular and notably Angular-UI Router and use Jade:
My index.jade looks like this:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset='UTF-8')
        meta(name='fragment', content='!')
        base(href='/')
        title Node Express Angular Example
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='./css/style.css')
    body(style='', ng-app='myApp', ng-cloak)
        include partials/header
        div(ui-view)

        script(src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')
        script(src='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js')
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js')
        script(src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js')
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-sanitize.js')
        script(src='./js/app.js')
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', 
    function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url:'/home',
            templateUrl: './partials/partial-home.jade'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url:'/about',
            template: 'This is the about page'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true)
    .hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

And my partial-home.jade looks like this:

```
div.jumbotron
    div.container.text-center
        h1 Home Page
        p This page is a draft in progress
```

I don't have a problem viewing the 'About' page, but I can not view the Home page.
I tried also to replace div(ui-view) with `<div ui-view></div>` in index.jade as was suggested in some other SO post but to no effect. Any clues?

Edit: There was a spelling mistake in app.js, it's templateUrl instead of templateURL. However it still does not render the proper partial-home.jade, what comes inside the ui-view is actually the same as index.jade. My server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var path = require('path');

app.set('views', __dirname+'/client/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.url + req.method);
    res.render('index');    
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Express Server listening on ' + port);
});
```

Comment: I think this should be configured on the server side. It is the server side that should render the jade template if I'm not entirely mistaken. When the server delivers the jade template it should render it right?

Comment: Look in the browser developer tools network tab at the response when the `./partials/partial-home.jade` template is loaded. Is it really rendered HTML or still the raw jade syntax?

Comment: I found out that my first mistake was a spelling mistake: it should be  templateUrl instead of templateURL. Now it seems that it reloads the entire index.jade in ui-view but still not with partial-home.jade, I believe it's due to the routing defined server side in Express, will amend my question accordingly.

Comment: @PeterLyons for the ./partials/partial-home.jade I have a status 200 and the response is in html BUT the response looks like index.jade not partial-home.jade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so express doesn't auto-render views. It will automatically send static files, but not render dynamic views, you so need an explicit route to match the partials and call `res.render` to convert them from jade to HTML before sending to the browser. Try something along these lines, putting this BEFORE your wildcard route for `index`.

```
app.use("/partials", function (req, res) {
  res.render(req.path);
});
```

Comment: It seems there were several things wrong in my code:

Comment: I have tried your solution and it didn't work properly, maybe I don't know to do it the right way. It seems there were several things wrong in my code. 1)Initially $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); was before $stateProvider in my app.js which triggered some kind of infinite loop 2)Once I use Angular routing system, I can not serve Jade templates, so the templateUrls inside $stateProvider have to be html templates. I am still quite confused how to best combine routes defined with Express and routes defined in AngularJs (I had to re-comment as SO doesn't let me edit for more than 5mn)

Comment: ui-route with jade existing a problem still

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents:
Why is it necessary for you to have the server render the page?
If the reason is that you need to pass in data on initial load (thinking like a JSON string somewhere, [something like this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/03/25/bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data-from-aspnet-mvc)), I would do it on bootstrapping ([a follow up from the same author on how to go about that](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data)).

Barring that reason, I can't really think of any other reason to have the server do the rendering. Compile your jade templates with gulp or better yet in webpack (HTMLWebpack plugin for the landing page is nice).