# Load Pug Views with UI router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, pug, ngroute

I am trying to load jade views using the mean stack, esp using angular UI router, and pug is just jade(in case if you were unaware of the namechange)
my folder structure looks something like this

```
|-- bin
|   `-- www
|-- bower.json
|-- models
|   `-- schools.js
|-- mysession.vim
|-- node_modules
|   |-- body-parser
|   |-- cookie-parser
|   |-- debug
|   |-- express
|   |-- gulp
|   |-- mongoose
|   |-- mongoose-currency
|   |-- morgan
|   |-- pug
|   `-- serve-favicon
|-- note.txt
|-- package.json
|-- public
|   |-- css
|   |-- img
|   |-- includes
|   |-- js
|   |-- vendor
|   `-- views
|-- routes
|   |-- dashboard.js
|   |-- index.js
|   `-- users.js
`-- server.js
```

The views to be rendered are inside /public/views/partials

and my app.js(angular) and server.js(express) looks something like this

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
angular.module("myedu",['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard',{
            url:'dashboard',
            views: {
                        head: 'assadashboard'
                    }
            })

            .state('add',{
            url: 'dashboard/add',
            views :{
                        head: "/partials/add"
                    }
            })

            .state('modify',{
            url: 'dashboard/modify',
            views :{
                        head: "/partials/modify"
                    }
            });
            //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    });
```

**server.js**

```
//I HAVE CUT DOWN REQUIRE STATEMENTS AND SOME MORE OBVIOUS LINES

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'public/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


//TO GET AND RENDER PARTIAL VIEWS  
//SEE THIS PART SO
app.get('/partials/:name',function (req,res) {
   res.render('partials/'+req.params.name);
});

//THE CATCH ALL ROUTE
app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.render("index");
});


//THIS GOES OFF TO /bin/www to have the express server run


module.exports = app;
```

Now that these are shown; 
Here are shot pug templates that I've for layout and index and the one of the partials.

**layout.pug** /public/includes/layout.pug
This loads the JS scripts from another file named scripts.pug in the same directory

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="myedu")
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/vendor/semantic/semantic.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
  body
    div(class="ui grid")
      div(class="three wide column adminside") 
        h2 Welcome to MYEDU
      div(class="eleven wide column") 
        block content 
    include scripts
```

**index.pug** /public/views/index.pug

```
extends ../includes/layout.pug

block content
  div(ui-view="head")
```

**modify.pug** (this is a partial that I am trying to render, it lives in /public/views/partials)

```
p This is the json with modified data
h2 I am a partial
```

I hope I was able to state my problem correctly, I am struggling with this for several days now; I am able to get results with ngRoute but problems are with uiRoute.

Comment: Hi, @hrishikesh-barman, I was hoping for answers here too. As for getting this solved, from your question it's difficult for me to see what _isn't_ working for you. What is going wrong and what did you want to happen?

Comment: I think the problem is with ui-router. It apparently doesn't *care* about pug, or jade, or anything, and simply inserts the target content into your page. That's why I see the raw `pug` code rendered, and I guess you see the same...?

I'm coming to the conclusion that the only way to do this is to have a `grunt` script to pre-compile the jade/pug into html that is then served from some location.

Comment: For what it's worth the answer here seems to outline the issue. It's a pity, but shouldn't be a surprise. Express is just rendering what it's told to.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989483/angular-ui-router-loading-jade-template?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular-ui router loading jade template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989483/angular-ui-router-loading-jade-template)